# remove digital signature from document with itextsharp library

Tags: vb.net, itext

good night,

I am working with itextsharp and want to remove the digital signatures from the document. I want to remove them not flatten them.

I found this code to flatten, what would be the variant to delete the signature.

I will appreciate any help.

Observation: I do not have the name of the signature field, it must be removed from any signed document.

Thanks a lot,

I'm working with visual studio 2019 and
itextsharp 5.5.13.2

Greetings.

```
Protected Sub ManipulatePdf(ByVal dest As String)
    Dim pdf As PdfReader = New PdfReader(SRC)
    Dim stamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(pdf, New FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    stamper.FormFlattening = True
    stamper.Close()  
End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly DEST As String = "c:\temp1\2.pdf"
Public Shared ReadOnly SRC As String = "c:\temp1\1.pdf"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(DEST)
    file.Directory.Create()
    ManipulatePdf(DEST)
End Sub
```

**Code update to find and remove signatures, not working yet.**

```
Protected Sub ManipulatePdf(ByVal dest As String)
    Dim pdf As PdfReader = New PdfReader(SRC)
    Dim acro As AcroFields = pdf.AcroFields
    Dim stamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(pdf, New FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    Dim nombrfirma As List(Of String) = acro.GetSignatureNames()

    For Each firma As String In nombrfirma
        Dim signature As AcroFields.Item = stamper.AcroFields.GetFieldItem(firma)
        For i = 0 To i < signature.Size
            signature.GetWidget(i).Clear()
            signature.GetMerged(i).Clear()
            signature.GetValue(i).Clear()
            i += 1
        Next
    Next

    'stamper.FormFlattening = True
    stamper.Close()
    pdf.Close()

End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly DEST As String = "c:\temp1\2.pdf"
Public Shared ReadOnly SRC As String = "c:\temp1\1.pdf"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(DEST)
    file.Directory.Create()
    ManipulatePdf(DEST)
End Sub
```

Comment: In that case you should find all signature fields, remove them from the **AcroForm**, and remove all references to their widget annotations from the pages.

Comment: So what should be the end result? A document with many empty signature form fields or a document with no signature form fields at all?

Comment: must be a document without any signature fields.

Comment: Is it really so hard to indent things properly so the code is actually readable?